# Trouble obtaining data from multiple *.root files...but no problems using only one

Tags: python-3.x, uproot

I am using pythong version 3.6.5 and have a jagged TTree with a multi-dimensional structure. This data is spread over more than 1000 files, all with the same identical TTree structure.

suppose I have two files though and I'll call them
fname1.root
fname2.root

The following code has no problem opening either of these by itself:

```
import uproot as upr
import awkward
import boost_histogram as bh
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#
# define a plotting program
# def plotter(h)
#
# preparing the file location for files
pth = '/fullpathName/'
fname1 = 'File755.root'
fname2 = 'File756.root'
fileList = [pth+fname1, pth+fname2]
#
# print out the path and filename that I've made to show the user
for file in fileList:
    print(file)
print('\n')
#
# Let's make a histogram This one has 50 bins, starts at zero and ends at 1000.0
# It will be a histogram of Jet pT's. 
jhist = bh.histogram(bh.axis.regular(50,0.0,1000.0))
#
#show what you've just done
print(jhist)
#
# does not work, only fills first file!
for chunk in upr.iterate(fileList,"bTag_AntiKt4EMTopoJets",["jet_pt"]):
    jhist.fill(chunk[b"jet_pt"][:, :2].flatten()*0.001)
#
#
# what does my histogram look like?
ptHist = plt.bar(jhist.axes[0].centers, jhist.view(), width=jhist.axes[0].widths)
plt.show()
```

As I said, the above code works if I put only ONE file in 'fileList'.

The naive thing to do doesn't work. 
If I create a 'list' of files using

```
files = [pth+fname1 , pth+fname2]
```

and re-run that code. I get the following error...which is very much the same error I have been getting all along.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 48, in <module>
  File "/home/huffman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uproot/tree.py", line 116, in iterate
    for tree, branchesinterp, globalentrystart, thispath, thisfile in _iterate(path, treepath, branches, awkward, localsource, xrootdsource, httpsource, **options):
  File "/home/huffman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uproot/tree.py", line 163, in _iterate
    file = uproot.rootio.open(path, localsource=localsource, xrootdsource=xrootdsource, httpsource=httpsource, **options)
  File "/home/huffman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uproot/rootio.py", line 54, in open
    return ROOTDirectory.read(openfcn(path), **options)
  File "/home/huffman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uproot/rootio.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    openfcn = lambda path: MemmapSource(path, **kwargs)
  File "/home/huffman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uproot/source/memmap.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._source = numpy.memmap(self.path, dtype=numpy.uint8, mode="r")
  File "/cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/views/LCG_94python3/x86_64-slc6-gcc8-opt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/memmap.py", line 264, in __new__
    mm = mmap.mmap(fid.fileno(), bytes, access=acc, offset=start)
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: By the way, try executing your examples—they won't work because they have syntax errors and changing variable names. I'm guilty of the same thing: I wrote the response below on a phone and didn't test it, but if it's wrong, just edit it. You might not have enough points to do that, but I think it will give me the option to review the suggested edits.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy arrays are just an interface for convenience—i.e. you can transform it with one function call, rather than iterating in an explicit loop over chunks. Internally, lazy arrays contain an implicit loop over chunks, so if you're running out of memory one way, you would be the other way.

Your problem is not closing files (they're memory-mapped, so "closing" didn't have a clear meaning—they're a view into memory that the operating system is allocating for itself, anyway)—your problem is with deleting arrays. That's the only thing that can use up all the memory on your computer.

There are a few things you can do here: one is to

```py
for chunk in uproot.iterate(files, "bTag_AntiKt4EMTopoJets", ["jet_pt", "jet_eta"]):
    # fill with chunk[b"jet_pt"] and chunk[b"jet_eta"], which correspond
    # to the same sets of events, one-to-one.
```

to explicitly loop over the chunks ("explicit" because you see and control the loop here, and because you have to specify which branches you want to load into the dict `chunk`). You can control the size of the chunks with `entrysteps`. The other is to

```py
cache = uproot.ArrayCache("1 GB")
events = uproot.lazyarrays(files, "bTag_AntiKt4EMTopoJets", cache=cache)
```

to keep the loop implicit. The `ArrayCache` will throw out chunks of arrays, so that they have to be loaded again, if it gets to the 1 GB limit. If you make that limit too small, it won't be able to hold one chunk, but if you make it too large, you'll run out of memory.

By the way, although you're reporting a memory issue, there's another major performance issue with your code: you're looking over events in Python. Instead of

```py
events.jet_pt[i][:2]*0.001
```

to get the jet pT for event `i`, do

```py
events.jet_pt[:, :2]*0.001
```

for the jet pT of all events as a single array. You might then need to `.flatten()` that array to fit the histogram's `fill` method.

Comment: I've tried using your 'cache' method and still have problems, even when it is set to only 10 kB. I've amended my original question with the exact memory error. 
I'm going to try your 'chunck' suggestion next.

Comment: In fact, this 'cache' method doesn't even work with a single file, even though the 'open' method I started with does work with a single file.

Comment: Oh and by the way, although your suggestion about improving the speed of my code is very welcome I'm not sure if, in the end, I can actually take advantage of it. This 'events' TTree has columns in it that I would want to correlate across. for example, I might want to only histogram jet_pt for the entries where jet_eta is within a given range. And there are other, more complex combinations of ways of selecting data for histograms I will want to do in the end. 
I think the outer for-loop over entries will be needed to always ensure all my 'events' are looking across the same entry.

Comment: Using ```for chunk in upr.iterate(fileList,"bTag_AntiKt4EMTopoJets",["jet_pt"]):```
and then ```jhist.fill(chunk[b"jet_pt"].flatten()*0.001)```
did not crash, however it seems to only fill the histogram with the contents of the first file. In addition, it is not obvious to me how one might only keep the first and second jets only, or how to cut on the jet_pt or another varible inside the stored TTree.

Comment: I extended the example to show how you'd get correlated chunks of `"jet_pt"` and `"jet_eta"` in each step of `uproot.iterate`. You can combine these with [columnar operations](https://github.com/jpivarski/2019-07-29-dpf-python#readme) to do some rather sophisticated analysis without a Python for loop. If you have a specific question about that, ask it with tag [tag:awkward-array].

As for the histogram overwriting itself, that's a question for the histogram library: there must be an interface that allows you to _add to_ a histogram, rather than _overwrite_ its contents.

Comment: I have to take back my comment just above this one. I am now getting a crash with two files again similar to the one I previously reported. 

I have edited my initial question to reflect my current state-of-play and using uproot.itierate  as suggested in the answers given here.

Comment: I have discovered that my problems with memory allocation when I use the lines `for chunk in upr.iterate(fileList,"bTag_AntiKt4EMTopoJets",["jet_pt"]): ` were related to a finite memory allocation that the computer I was using would allocate to interactive users. This restriction was removed when submitting a batch job and then the code ran on multiple files.

Comment: However, this does not strike me as a solution when there are thousands of 10 GB files that I need to go through. In the data model I'm using, every individual "event" is unconnected to every other. Hence every file is an independent set of data that does not rely on the other files. 

We really do need a mechanism to **close** a file or de-allocate the memory that file's data uses when one is finished with a given file....otherwise uproot will only be of limited use I'm afraid.

Comment: I think this problem is also outlined [here](https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot/issues/108)